# Blazor component not refreshing

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

So I have a Blazor application in which a user logs in and the header component changes depending on whether a user is logged in or not. After the use logs in, they are redirected to the main home page, but the header component does not update unless I hit the refresh button on the browser. I tried using `StateHasChanged()`. Here is my relevant code in the header component:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
{
    <div class="header-user-widget">
        <button class="btn btn-cart">
            Cart <span class="badge badge-cart">@CartCount</span>
        </button>
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> @FirstName @LastName
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt header-sign-out" @onclick="SignOutClicked"></i>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string FirstName { get; set; }
    private string LastName { get; set; }
    private int CartCount { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var page = NavManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavManager.Uri).ToLower();
        var cookie = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("Cookies.get", "Login");

        if (!page.StartsWith("login"))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie))
            {
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/Login");
                return;
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie))
        {
            var decodedCookie = cookie.FromBase64String();

            FirstName = CookieHelper.GetValueFromKey(decodedCookie, "FirstName");
            LastName = CookieHelper.GetValueFromKey(decodedCookie, "LastName");
        }

        CartCount = await NumberOfItemsInCart();
    }
}
```

And here is my login page:

```
@page "/login"

@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<LoginBox OnLoginButtonClick="@LoginButtonClicked" />

@code {

    private async Task LoginButtonClicked(LoginBoxReturnModel model)
    {
        var cookieString = $"UserId={model.UserId}|FirstName={model.FirstName}|LastName={model.LastName}|Email={model.EmailAddress}|IsAdmin={model.IsAdmin}";
        var encyptedString = cookieString.ToEncryptedBase64String();

        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Cookies.set", "Login", encyptedString);

        StateHasChanged(); // This line doesn't seem to have any effect
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Once the user logs in, they are properly redirected to `"/"` page, but the header is not updated. If I hit F5 in the browser to refresh it, then the header is correct. I feel like what is going on is that the application is navigating before the `StateHasChanged()` line has any time to refresh, thus it is never refreshing. If this is the case, how should I be implementing this?

Comment: Where's the rest of the header and the page it appears in? Blazor is essentially React# which means components react/refresh in response to changes to their properties. What you posted shows that data is only loaded when the component is initialized the first time, loading data from cookies and unspecified sources. There are no component properties though, or something that actually changes the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The header component is being used in my main layout page. I can post it, if you want, but it's just a standard layout page with my `<Header />` tag in it. I understand that no component properties are being changed. That is why I am calling `StateHasChanged()` because my understanding is that calling that method forces components to refresh regardless of whether or not a property is changed.

Comment: On which component? `StateHasChanged ` doesn't mean `RefreshAll`. That's why I said it's React#. The components refresh only if *their* state (their parameters) changed. Instead of *every* component in a page refreshing, only the affected components do. The header you posted doesn't even have parameters, so it can't receive any state from the outside or respond to changes

Comment: If you want the user and cart count properties to change dynamically, they should be exposed as [component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-parameters) that will be modified by the header's parent

Comment: I misunderstood what `StateHasChanged` does. I was under the impression that calling that would refresh all the visible components on the page, not just the component it's called from. So you're saying the way to make this work is to create a public method in the component, like `Update()` or something and then if the header needs to be refreshed, just called that `Update()` method, which in turn reads the cookie and updates itself accordingly?

Comment: I would recommend using some type of event bus to listen for the login and update the header accordingly. I've used this library before https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.EventAggregator.

Comment: No. I'm saying you should understand how React and Blazor components actually work, forget any concepts you bring from eg WinForms or WebForms, because this is *completely* different. The component will update itself if you modify its parameters. The *parent* should provide the modified data to those parameters, not the control itself.

Comment: @NechemiaHoffmann there's no need for this if components are used as designed. This would add a lot of complexity for a scenario already covered by the basic design of Blazor *and React*. React doesn't need any event aggregators to update the view when a user logs in

Comment: @Icemanind You could do that but you will need a ref to the header component and the `Update()` method will need to call `InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged())`.

Comment: @NechemiaHoffmann in fact *all* that's needed here is to update the state of the root component and eg set the `User` and `Cart` parameters to a new value. All child components that care about those parameters will update themselves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The problem is this component lays inside a layout file, which means there really is no parent. The direction needs to flow the other way. The child component needs to modify or notify something inside the parent header control.

Comment: @Icemanind there is *always* a parent - the layout component, the root, the app. In fact, the *app* is the class that should know about users, where to find services etc

Comment: `IsAdmin` in a cookie?

Comment: @henkholterman - the cookie string is encrypted with AES128 then converted into a Base64 string. That string is what's stored in the cookie.

Comment: Yes, but who owns/manages that crypto key?  You run in the user's browser.

Comment: @henkholterman the key is stored on a SQL server database. My SQL server.

Comment: Well, if you say so. But the encrypt/decrypt calls don't look like API calls, no await.

Comment: You do realize that DIY security makes hackers happy?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - First, I only posted relevant code to this issue.  I didn't post any of the security related calls. Second, this app isn't guarding Ft. Knox. It's a recipe program I'm writting for my girlfriend. No personal data or anything like that. The most a hacker will get if they hack this program is a recipe for Chicken Cacciatora or something like that.

Comment: Back to the question: can you link to the Cookies / CookieHelper libaries? Because "If I hit F5 [ it works ]" makes me wonder how what is going on.

Comment: And why don't you use LocalStorage or SessionStorage?  I have trouble seeing the usefulness of cookies in a SPA.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the StateHasChanged(), your navigating from "/login" to "/". The true should  force the load of the cookie like f5 is doing.

```
NavManager.NavigateTo("/",true);
```